NestJS interceptor doesn't work with StreamableFile
When using timeout interceptor (TimeoutInterceptor in timeout.interceptor.ts) with EP that returns StreamableFile, the interceptor doesn't work - it doesn't early return a response when timeout passed.
It does work when returning a list of string.
Issue in nestjs/nest
How to reproduce
Repro repo

Start the app in dev mode
Visit http://localhost:3000/foo/file
The foo/file endpoint takes 3 seconds to resolve while the timeout interceptor sets a timeout of 10 ms

Current behavior
File is downloaded.
Expected behavior
A response with code 408 should be returned.
Note that the timeout interceptor works when submitting a request to GET /foo
Set an interceptor that returns a timeout response if certain amount of time passed before the request was resolved. It doesn't work for endpoints that return StreamableFile
